# Associativity of symmetric difference of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

By $A\oplus B$ we denote the symmectric difference of two sets. The definition is $A\oplus B =(A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$. Now I hope to show that $A\oplus (B\oplus C) = (A\oplus B)\oplus C$. I remember that there's an elegant proof, but I forget its detail. (The first step is to show $A\oplus (A\oplus B) = B$, and maybe applying this formula, we can obtain associativity.)

Comment: @julien: $\oplus$ is "XOR", which is the symmetric difference. It is not an unusual notation in some places.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, thanks a lot! I did not know that.

Answer (score 21):

You could use characteristic functions to make it more algebraic. Observe
$$
1_{A\cap B}=1_A\cdot 1_B \qquad\mbox{and}\qquad 1_{A\Delta B}=1_A+1_B-2\cdot 1_{A\cap B}.
$$
Then
$$
1_{A\Delta(B\Delta C)}=1_A+1_{B\Delta C}-2\cdot1_{A\cap (B\Delta C)}
$$
$$
=1_A+1_B+1_C-2\cdot1_{B\cap C}-2\cdot1_A\cdot(1_B+1_C-2\cdot1_{B\cap C})
$$
$$
=1_A+1_B+1_C-2\cdot1_{A\cap B}-2\cdot1_{B\cap C}-2\cdot1_{C\cap A}+4\cdot1_{A\cap B\cap C}.
$$
I used that $\cap $ is associative to make sense of $A\cap (B\cap C)=A\cap B\cap C$. To be consistent, this can also be proven with characteristic functions:
$$
1_{A\cap(B\cap C)}=1_A1_{B\cap C}=1_A1_B1_C=1_{A\cap B}1_C=1_{(A\cap B)\cap C}.
$$

Now starting from $1_{(A\Delta B)\Delta C}$, you end up with the same symmetric formula. Hence your two sets have the same characteristic functions, which means that they are equal.

Comment: I think that this is a great method to prove such a thing! as it can be easily used to prove that $+$ is associative in boolean rings induced from boolean algebras as $+$ here represent the symmetric difference of elements in the boolean algebra.

Comment: Why is $1_{A\Delta B}= 1_A + 1_B - 1_{A \cap B}$? For $x\in A\cap B$, this function is $1 + 1 - 1 =1$, but $x \notin A \Delta B$?

Comment: @Roland It should be $\chi_{A\Delta B} = \chi_A + \chi_B -2\chi_{A\cap B}$. But goddamn...this proof idea is sexy as hell.

Answer (score 9):

$A \oplus B$ contains those elements (of the given basic set) which belong to exactly one of the sets $A$ and $B$. Thus, $A \oplus (B \oplus C)$ consists of those elements which belong to exactly one of the sets $A$ and $B \oplus C$, i.e. to exactly one *or* all three of the sets $A$, $B$ and $C$. This shows $A \oplus (B \oplus C) = (A \oplus B) \oplus C$.

There is also a more algebraic proof, using the isomorphism of structures $(P(X),\oplus,\cap) \cong (\mathbb{F}_2^X,+,*)$, which immediately implies that $(P(X),\oplus,\cap)$ is a ring.

Comment: You are missing the elements that are in all three of the sets $A, B, C$. In general, $\oplus A_{i}$ consists of the elements that belong to an *odd* number of $A_{i}$.

Comment: Thank you. $\phantom{   }$

Answer (score 2):

Another way to prove this, is to first prove that $\;x \in A \oplus B \;\equiv\; x \in A \not\equiv x \in B\;$, and then use the analogous law of logic ($\;\not\equiv\;$ is associative, i.e. $\;P \not\equiv (Q \not\equiv R) \;\equiv\; (P \not\equiv Q) \not\equiv R\;$).

The precise proof of that law of logic depends on the propositional logic laws or axioms you would be allowed to use, but here is one example.$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
%$

Note that we are asked to prove that a given expression is symmetric in $\;P\;$ and $\;R\;$.  Therefore we calculate for any $\;P, Q, R\;$:
$$\calc
  \tag{*}
  P \not\equiv (Q \not\equiv R)
\op{\equiv}\hint{case split on $\;Q\;$ -- this seems the most symmetrical thing to do}
  (Q \land (P \not\equiv (\true \not\equiv R))) \;\lor\;
  (\lnot Q \land (P \not\equiv (\false \not\equiv R)))
\op{\equiv}\hint{simplify}
  (Q \land (P \equiv R)) \;\lor\;
  (\lnot Q \land (P \not\equiv R))
\endcalc$$

And because $\;\equiv\;$ and $\;\not\equiv\;$ are symmetric, that last expression is symmetric in $\;P\;$ and $\;R\;$, and therefore the first one is too.

Therefore
$$\calc
  \tag{*}
  P \not\equiv (Q \not\equiv R)
\op{\equiv}\hint{$\Ref{*}$ is symmetric in $\;P\;$ and $\;R\;$, see above}
  R \not\equiv (Q \not\equiv P)
\op{\equiv}\hint{$\;\not\equiv\;$ is symmetric, twice}
  (P \not\equiv Q) \not\equiv R
\endcalc$$

$%
\endgroup
%$

Comment: With a propositional logic proof, from whatever propositional logic axioms you happen to be working in. Let me see if I have time to update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a second.

$$
i_{\left( A∆B \right)}≡i_A+i_B\left( mod2 \right) .Thus\,\,i_{\left( A∆B \right) ∆C}=i_{A∆\left( B∆C \right)}≡i_A+i_B+i_C\left( mod2 \right) .
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a set.
Let $A,B,C$ be subsets of $X$.
Let $A':=X\setminus A$.
Let $B':=X\setminus B$.
Let $C':=X\setminus C$.
Then, $$X=(A\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A'\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B'\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B\cap C')\sqcup(A'\cap B'\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B'\cap C')\sqcup(A'\cap B\cap C')\sqcup(A'\cap B'\cap C').$$

The following equalities are logically obvious.

$$A=(A\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B'\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B\cap C')\sqcup(A\cap B'\cap C').$$

$$B=(A\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A'\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B\cap C')\sqcup(A'\cap B\cap C').$$

$$C=(A\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A'\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B'\cap C)\sqcup(A'\cap B'\cap C).$$

$$A\cup B=(A\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A'\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B'\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B\cap C')\sqcup(A\cap B'\cap C')\sqcup(A'\cap B\cap C').$$

$$A\cap B=(A\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B\cap C').$$

$$(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)=(A'\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B'\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B'\cap C')\sqcup(A'\cap B\cap C').$$

$$((A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B))\cup C=(A\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A'\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B'\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B'\cap C')\sqcup(A'\cap B\cap C')\sqcup(A'\cap B'\cap C).$$

$$((A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B))\cap C=(A'\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B'\cap C).$$

$$(((A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B))\cup C)\setminus (((A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B))\cap C)=(A\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B'\cap C')\sqcup(A'\cap B\cap C')\sqcup(A'\cap B'\cap C).$$

If we replace $A$ with $B$ and $B$ with $C$ and $C$ with $A$ in the above equality, then we get the following equality:

$$(((B\cup C)\setminus (B\cap C))\cup A)\setminus (((B\cup C)\setminus (B\cap C))\cap A)=(B\cap C\cap A)\sqcup(B\cap C'\cap A')\sqcup(B'\cap C\cap A')\sqcup(B'\cap C'\cap A).$$

Since $\cup$ and $\cap$ are commutative, we get the following equality:

$$(A\cup ((B\cup C)\setminus (B\cap C)))\setminus (A\cap((B\cup C)\setminus (B\cap C)))=(A\cap B\cap C)\sqcup(A'\cap B\cap C')\sqcup(A'\cap B'\cap C)\sqcup(A\cap B'\cap C').$$

So, $$(((A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B))\cup C)\setminus (((A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B))\cap C)=(A\cup ((B\cup C)\setminus (B\cap C)))\setminus (A\cap((B\cup C)\setminus (B\cap C))).$$