# Proof that the symmetric difference is associative

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that the symmetric difference looks like that when having three sets `A,B,C`:

[image]

I want to make a prove with Venn diagrams to prove the associativity of the symmetric difference. What are some good ways to create this proof in a clear way?

I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: Writing "symmetric difference is associative" in the search box above gives this as a first result, and [this as a close second](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332763/associativity-of-symmetric-difference-of-sets). Does this question show any research efforts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, to prove associativity of the symmetric difference of three sets, you are aiming to show that $$A \Delta (B \Delta C) = (A\Delta B)\Delta C\tag{1}$$

where, given any two sets, $X, Y$, $$X \Delta Y = (X \cup Y)\setminus (X \cap Y)$$

To show the equality given by $(1)$ using *Venn Diagrams*, you need only create a Venn Diagram  corresponding to the set defined by the left-hand of $(1)$, and create a Venn Diagram that corresponds to the set defined by the right-hand side of $(1)$, and show that the two diagrams depict precisely the same set (i.e., that the two Venn diagrams are precisely the same).

It is also a worthwhile exercise to use, e.g., "element chasing" to provide an "algebraic" proof that the equality given by $(1)$ holds, and hence, that the symmetric difference is associative.