# Prove that $A \Delta (B \Delta C) = (A \Delta B) \Delta C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $A \Delta (B \Delta C) = (A \Delta B) \Delta C$.

$A \Delta (B \Delta C) = A \Delta ((B - C) \cup (C - B))$

$= [A - ((B-C) \cup (C-B))] \cup [((B-C)\cup(C-B)) - A]$

$= [A \cap \sim((B-C)\cup(C-B))] \cup [((B-C)\cup(C-B)) \cap \sim A]$

From here I am unsure how to proceed and get to what I want.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332763/associativity-of-symmetric-difference-of-sets) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452692/).

Comment: I realize there are other topics like this one but I would like to figure mine out from just a pure set theoretic idea in the way that I have done.