# Symmetric difference using Venn diagrams (Discrete Math)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[image]

My question is about that image:

> Is this the correct Venn diagram for part c ? Why is there a red region in the middle that is painted ? Where did this red region came from?

And about the relation:

> This is true?How can I visualize this using the Venn diagram? $$(A \Delta B) \Delta C = A \Delta (B \Delta C)$$

Comment: I found this picture online, and it is really similar to the venn diagram that I have on paper, except I don't have the red region. Is it required ? Would it make any difference for the equations that I have versus the equation in the picture ?

Comment: I think youre trying to prove that symmetric difference has property c doesn't?[

Comment: I am trying to find out the truth or falsity for sets A, B, C subsets of u.

Comment: Could you please clarify this for m. Do I need the red painted area ? If yes, why ?

Comment: the blue(violet?) area plus the red area are the symmetric difference of A,B and C [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#Properties)

Comment: So yes you need the red part to prove that symmetric difference is associative

Comment: Ok I see that is what I needed to know. Thank you very much !

Comment: (+1)Ok I'll try to write an good informative answer for that question.

Comment: Yeah, I am sure in the future, people will find it helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#Properties) that symmetric difference has an important property: *The symmetric difference is associative!* There are different ways to prove that, you can see in this related Math.SE questions: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452692/proof-that-the-symmetric-difference-is-associative) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332763/associativity-of-symmetric-difference-of-sets).

And you can see other proof that I personally like [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_Difference_is_Associative).

But your question is exactly:

> *Is this the correct diagram for the symmetric difference of the given A,B,C sets?*

The answer is **yes**. There is a lot of ways to see it.

---

You can use the diagram to see what would be the symmetric difference:

> $$A\Delta B$$
>   [image]

So the symmetric difference is the area of $A$ and $B$ without the intersection. See that the area taken out were the area of $A \cup B - (A\cap B)$. This is the definition of symmetric difference.

> $$A\cap B$$
>   [image]

We have that the set 
$C$ is

> $$C$$
>   [image]

Now, for the set $A\Delta B \Delta C$ we must take the areas of the both  sets above and take the intersection. See that the center (in your question the red area) is in $C$ but is not in $A\Delta B$ so it is not an intersection, so should be considered! But the pink areas that are shown in the figure below are the intersection. So we will have

> $$(A\Delta B) \cap C$$
>   [image]

So we take the area of all the unions and take out the pink areas. We are left with the symmetric difference of $A,B$ and $C$:

> $$A\Delta B \Delta C $$
>   [image]

---

Other way is to use the relations [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_Difference_is_Associative) and construct a Venn diagram using the relations. For example

> $$A\Delta B \Delta C = \displaystyle \left({A \cap \overline B \cap \overline C}\right) \cup \left({\overline A \cap B \cap \overline C}\right) \cup \left({\overline A \cap \overline B \cap C}\right) \cup \left({A \cap B \cap C}\right)$$

Where the bar above means that we take the [complement](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Set_Complement) of the set. If we name each of the sets that are been united: $X := \left({A \cap \overline B \cap \overline C}\right)$, $Y := \left({\overline A \cap B \cap \overline C}\right)$, $Z := \left({\overline A \cap \overline B \cap C}\right)$, $W := \left({A \cap B \cap C}\right)$ in this nomenclature we have $$A\Delta B\Delta C = X \cup Y \cup Z \cup W$$
We will have the above union and each of the sets will have the name that we give above inside them

> [image]

Comment: What a clarification my friend. Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of looking at this.

Logically, the symmetric difference corresponds to XOR:

$A \Delta B = \{ x|x \in A \: XOR \: x \in B \}$

Since the XOR is associative:

$A \: XOR \: (B \: XOR \: C) \Leftrightarrow (A \: XOR \: B) \: XOR \: C$

we can have XOR's with any number of terms.

Now, what would make a generalized XOR statement with $n$ terms true?  It turns out that it is true when an odd number of terms are true.

Applied back to sets, this means that $A \Delta B \Delta C$ contains all elements that are in exactly an odd number of sets, i.e. in exactly one or all three.  And that you see nicely in the Venn diagram.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your information.