# Set Theory Proof with Delta: $(A\mathrel{\triangle} B)\mathrel{\triangle} C = A\mathrel{\triangle} (B\mathrel{\triangle} C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$(A\mathrel{\triangle} B)\mathrel{\triangle} C = A\mathrel{\triangle} (B\mathrel{\triangle} C)$$

Any thoughts? Would I use set theory laws to prove this?

I do not really know where to start, is there set theory laws for the delta notation or would I have to expand on everything?

Comment: There are; your task here is to prove one of them, the associative law for symmetric difference. You can expand in terms of other set operations whose algebraic properties you already know and use those properties. You can chase slements to show that each side is a subset of the other. Or you can prove that each side is the set of things that belong to an odd number of the sets $A,B$, and $C$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Associativity of symmetric difference of sets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332763/associativity-of-symmetric-difference-of-sets)

Comment: Searching for "symmetric difference is associative" would bring up a number of results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Extreme) Brute Force $\downarrow$

[image]

[Sorry for posting picture; prefer to typeset in my LaTeX editor: \newcommand + autocompletion; I welcome edits to my post which replaces the picture with genuine code]

Answer (score 1):

One way is brute force: (1) Some points are not in $A$, $B$, or $C$; (2) Some are in $A$ but not in $B$ or $C$; (3) Some are in $B$ and not in $A$ or $C$; (4) Some are in $C$ and not in $A$ or $B$; (5) Some are in $A$ and $B$ but not $C$; (6) Some are in $A$ and $C$ but not $B$; (7) Some are in $B$ and $C$ but not $A$; (8) Some in in all three.

Now figure out which of those points are in $(A\mathrel{\triangle} B)\mathrel{\triangle} C$ and which are in $A\mathrel{\triangle} (B\mathrel{\triangle} C)$, and see if you get the same ones both times.

That's brute force.  Another way is to show that the indicator function of $A\mathrel{\triangle}B$ is the mod-$2$ sum of the indicator functions of $A$ and $B$, and then show that mod-$2$ addition is associative.

**PS:** OK, here's a table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
x\in A & x\in B & x\in C & x\in A\mathrel{\triangle} (B\mathrel{\triangle} C) & x\in (A\mathrel{\triangle} B) \mathrel{\triangle} C \\
\hline
f & f & f & \text{?} & \text{?} \\[12pt]
T & f & f & \text{?} & \text{?} \\
f & T & f & \text{?} & \text{?} \\
f & f & T & \text{?} & \text{?} \\[12pt]
T & T & f & \text{?} & \text{?} \\
T & f & T & \text{?} & \text{?} \\
f & T & T & \text{?} & \text{?} \\[12pt]
T & T & T & \text{?} & \text{?}
\end{array}
$$
Fill in the blanks and see if the last two columns match.

Comment: How would I show its associative? I just started set theory.

Comment: Just proceed as in my first two paragraphs above.  That does it.

Answer (score 1):

Define an operation $\delta$ where $p\delta q\Leftrightarrow \neg (p\Leftrightarrow q)$. Make a 0-1 table of $\delta$. It is easy to see that $x\in A\triangle B\Leftrightarrow (x\in A)\delta (x\in B)$. Finally show (for example by 0-1 method) that $\delta$ is associative.