# Symmetric difference and indicator function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[Associativity of symmetric difference of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332763/associativity-of-symmetric-difference-of-sets)

In that post it said the symmetric difference is $$1_{A\mathbin{\Delta} B} = 1_A + 1_B - 1_{A\cap B}$$

Why is it not $$1_{A\mathbin{\Delta} B}=1_A+1_B-2(1_{A\cap B})$$

I can't really see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

On $A\cap B$, the idicator function of $A\mathbin\Delta B$ should be $0$. However, the function $1_A + 1_B - 1_{A\cap B}$ has the value $1 + 1 - 1 = 1$ on $A\cap B$ and is the indicator function of $A\cup B$.

Another way to see $1_{A\mathbin\Delta B}= 1_A + 1_B - 2(1_{A \cap B})$ is to realize that $$1_{A\setminus B} = 1_A - 1_{A\cap B}$$ and $$1_{B \setminus A} =1_B - 1_{B \cap A}.$$

Since $A\mathbin\Delta B = (A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$ and this union is disjoint, you can write $1_{A \Delta B}$ as the sum of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can note that: $1_{A\Delta B}=1_{A\cup B}-1_{A\cap B}=(1_A+1_B-1_{A\cap B})-1_{A\cap B}=1_A+1_B-2.1_{A\cap B}=1_A+1_B-2.1_{A}.1_{B}$