# (A⊕B)⊕C = A⊕(B⊕C) how to prove

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove this equation. I thought about it and did the venn-diagram on the equation which shows me that the equation is true but I'm having a hard time coming up with a proper way to prove the equation. [Picute of the Venn-Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LePbB.png)

Comment: What does $\oplus$ stand for, here?

Comment: @Cornman, from the picture, symmetric difference.

Comment: A⊕B would equate to (A \ B) ∪ (A \ B)

Comment: mark, this is so long and tedious that I seriously doubt anyone will write the complete proof. When I was at uni, Venn-Diagrams were never allowed as proofs at exams. Except in this particular case. That's how tedious it is. Basically, as in any proof of this kind, you need to show $(A\oplus B)\oplus C \subseteq A\oplus(B\oplus C)$ and  $(A\oplus B)\oplus C \supseteq A\oplus(B\oplus C)$. So, take $x$ from one, write down what it means from definition and manipulate symbols until you arrive at the defnition of the other. Good luck!

Comment: Ah, [here's a nice proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332763/associativity-of-symmetric-difference-of-sets) using characteristic functions.

Answer (score 2):

An element $x$ is in $(A\oplus B)\oplus C$ iff it is in $A\oplus B$ or in $C$ but not in both. Iff it is either in exactly one of $A$ or $B$, or otherwise it is in $C$. Iff exactly one or all three of $A,\ B,\ C$ contains it. Iff the number of summands is *odd* in which it is contained.

The same conclusion applies to $A\oplus(B\oplus C)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Keep these equivalences in mind (or prove them should need be):$$\begin{align}(X\oplus Y)&=(X\cap Y^\complement)\cup(X^\complement\cap Y)\tag 1\\[2ex](X\oplus Y)^\complement&= (X\cap Y)\cup(X^\complement\cap Y^\complement)\tag 2\end{align}$$

So to begin...

$$\begin{align}(A\oplus B)\oplus C &= ((A\oplus B)\cap C^\complement)\cup((A\oplus B)^\complement\cap C)\\ &~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in (A\oplus B) \oplus C$ be arbitary. We will show $x \in A\oplus (B \oplus C)$, to show one inclusion at least.

Immediately we have two cases, which we again split:

1: $x \in A \oplus B$ and $x \notin C$.

1a: $x \in A$, $x \notin B$, $x \notin C$.

1b: $x \notin A$, $x \in B$, $x \notin C$.

2: $x \notin A \oplus B$ and $x \in C$.

2a: $x \in A$, $x \in B$, $x \in C$.

2b. $x \notin A$, $x \notin B$, $x \in C$.

Note that these four cases correspond to four areas in the Venn diagram, and also follow straight from the definition of the symmetric difference.
Also note that I use $x \notin A\oplus B$ iff ($x \in A$ and $x \in B$) or ($x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$).

Finishing the cases:

1a: $x \notin B\oplus C$ and $x \in A$ so $x \in A\oplus (B \oplus C)$.

1b: $x \in B \oplus C$ and $x \notin A$ so $x \in A\oplus (B \oplus C)$.

2a: $x \notin B \oplus C$ and $x \in A$ so $x \in A\oplus (B \oplus C)$.

2b: $x \in B \oplus C$ and $x \notin A$ so $x \in A\oplus (B \oplus C)$.

The reverse inclusion is easy, read all cases backwards....

Comment: This is @GrahamKemp's proof written out in cases instead of subformulae.