# An implication between two sets equalities involving symmetric difference operation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

If this happens
[image]

show this [image]

what i tried:

$ A^cΔB=AΔC  $ multpie both sides by ΔA

$ A^CΔAΔB=AΔAΔC             $

$  UΔB = ∅ΔC $

$ BΔU = CΔ∅==>B^c=C==>C=B^c $

is it correct?

Comment: I'd guess that the uppercase Delta means a symmetric difference of sets, but it would be good to say as much and indicate what principles you would allow the proof to be based on.

Comment: Your idea to "multipl[y] both sides by ΔA" can be [formally justified](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332763/associativity-of-symmetric-difference-of-sets) but it would be helpful to know the *context* in which you are trying to prove this.