# Symmetric Difference of a set is associative short proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $P(X)$ be the set of all possible subsets of $X$. If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are three sets in $P(X)$ Is there any short way to prove $A\Delta(B\Delta C)=(A\Delta B)\Delta C$. Where $A\Delta B=A \cup B-A\cap B$. I have tried the following
$A\Delta(B\Delta C)=A\Delta (B \cup C-B\cap C)=A\cup[B \cup C-B\cap C]-A\cap[B \cup C-B\cap C]$. Now I cant go further because I not know the properties of  intersection and union with difference.

Comment: This [vid](https://youtu.be/0qrrIY-13co) from The Math Sorcerer might help

Comment: See [Associativity of symmetric difference of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/332763/13130) and [these other questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/332763).

Answer (score 1):

Let $V=A\cup B\cup C.$ For any $S\subseteq V,$ let $S'=V\setminus S.$ For any $S,T\subseteq V$ let $S+T=S\cup T$ and $ST=S\cap T .$

Observe that for any $S,T\subseteq V$ we have $S\Delta T=ST'+S'T$ and $(S\Delta T)'=ST+S'T'.$

Therefore we have $$A\Delta (B\Delta C)=A(B\Delta C)'+A'(B\Delta C)=$$ $$=A(BC+B'C')+A'(BC'+B'C)=$$ $$=ABC+AB'C'+A'BC'+A'B'C.$$ And we have $$(A\Delta B)\Delta C=(A\Delta B)C'+(A\Delta B)'C=$$ $$=(AB'+A'B)C'+(AB+A'B')C=$$ $$=AB'C'+A'BC'+ABC+A'B'C.$$